# How can I create a custom element in Aurelia when the .js and .html are not in the same folder?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to create a custom element in Aurelia.  I used the getViewStrategy method to allow my html and js files to reside in different folders of my app, a js folder for js files and an html folder for html files.

The problem I am having is when I try to require the two files for my custom element, I get an error saying I am trying to register an Element when one with the same name already exists.

app.html

```
<require from="../Scripts/Templates/js/myTag.js"></require>
<require from="../Content/Templates/html/myTag.html"></require>

<my-tag></my-tag>
```

myTag.js

```
export class MyTag{
    getViewStrategy(){
        return '../../Templates/html/myTag.html';
    }
}
```

myTag.html

```
<template>
    <h4>MY TAG!!!</h4>
</template>
```

How can I register this custom element?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `@useView` decorator:

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=3d0a2ccf8af9b7e5b512a09f4dd6b81c**

```js
import {useView} from 'aurelia-framework';

@useView('../../../Content/Templates/html/myTag.html')
export class MyTag {
}
```